# Position data points in bar graphs in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have SSRS reports which has a column chart.

The column chart has 2 value: Actual and Target.

The actual value is displayed as column chart with data labels displayed
and target value as Range column (my data has different targets for different values and would like to display target line for each bar)

The problem which I am running into is that sometimes this target line gets displayed over the data labels and its hard to read the data value.

Is there any way to set these labels to display over the target line when this happens?

This is what is happening right now:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx_Po7ND9VtOcW8xN3JSNlk5NjQ/view?usp=sharing

Options I tried till now:

1) setting the target values as first series and actual as second series: In this case I don't get to see the target lines as bars gets painted over the target lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your Range Series' **Fill** color to use **Transparency** to allow the elements behind the line to be seen.

[image]

On another note, in the future you may want to do this with a **StripLine** on the axis rather than creating a new series.

http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/blogs/jeoc/archive/2013/07/23/adding-strip-lines-to-reports.aspx

http://blog.jontav.com/post/7067899413/axis-striplines-in-ssrs-charts

Comment: Thanks Hannover.. but the problem with this solution is that it changes the color of the target line and I require a specific color - Dark Orange. The other option which i tried was positioning the lable: =iif(Fields!EndValue.Value is nothing, "Auto",iif((Fields!TargetValue.Value - Fields!ActualValue.Value)/ Fields!EndValue.Value >=0.0075 And (Fields!TargetValue.Value - Fields!ActualValue.Value)/ Fields!EndValue.Value <=0.09 , "Bottom","Auto"))

Comment: However, the problem is that it works in Vertical bars but not in horizontal bars. The only problem with using Stripelines is that these target lines are not continous and may not have target for each bars (in which case still shows that stripline)